# See full report of User Engagement by Screen in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

First time user of Firebase here. I'm very confused on how to see the full report of user engagement by screens. In the Firebase dashboard, I can only see this:

[image]

Theres no link to view the full report of all screens.
In Google Analytics, I can see everything in a very trivial way.

Comment: This is a known feature request to Firebase Analytics. You can contact the support team to see if they will support it and when it will happen.

Comment: Why is it called the analytics for mobile apps if does not have this one? It seems like Im going back to Google Analytics

Comment: As I said, they are working on that. I'm not sure when it will be launched so that's why I'd recommend to contact them for the timeline.